# video streaming node js video controls not working on local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, video-streaming, html5-video

i want to add video to the node.js server but when i load it in the server the controls arent operating WHY?
(please keep the code minimal...for understanding)

```
//html5 video loading

<video width="320" height="240" controls>


  <source src="cat.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

//NOT LOADING

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>


  <source src="http://localhost:8080" type="video/mp4">



</video>
```

```
//my node js code is 

var http = require ("http");
var fs = require ("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res)

{
console.log ('request was made:'+req.url);
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+ '/index.html','utf8');
myReadStream.pipe(res);

});


server.listen(8080,'127.0.0.1');
console.log('YO BOSS');
```

Comment: i'm thinking about video.js is it the way to go?

Comment: Usage of Video.js or not has nothing to do with the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

With streaming media, the browser doesn't usually make just a request for the whole media file.  It will use [ranged requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to enable seeking.

Your response is ignoring the browser's range requests, and isn't even telling the browser how big the file is.  If the browser doesn't know how big it is, and knows you don't support range requests, it can't load the appropriate metadata and can't know how big the file is.

You can either implement all this yourself, or use Express.static to handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

in fact the answer was super easy \(^.^)//
Ijust add to add http://localhost:8080/cat.mp4
the answer was in the adress badly written after having added (cat.mp4) to the adress it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a folder and name it `public`.
Then, in your JavaScript file, after app is defined, put:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

All videos and images should reside in the folder.
You can use the files by simply putting their name as the `src`. Example: image1.ogg.